# Visual Studio 2013 Browser Link unavailable until the project is reloaded

Tags: visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I'm having a problem with Browser Link in Visual Studio 2013 - it is only available after unloading and reloading one of the projects within the solution.

From what I've seen, it doesn't matter which solution I try, whenever I open Visual Studio Browser Link is disabled until I reload a project - it doesn't even need to be a project with Browser Link enabled.

I've tried adding `<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="true" />` but that makes no difference.

I've come to the conclusion that it doesn't matter about the web.config settings, it is either a bug in Visual Studio 2013 or one of the add-ons is causing the problem. I removed the obvious add-ons but some I don't want to remove just yet (like xamarin and ReSharper (I tried suspending this)) but I can try that next week if no other solution works.

For the record, once I have reloaded a project Browser Link appears to work as expected.

Has anyone else had a similar experience?

**Update**

I've just discovered that the way I open Visual Studio makes a difference. If I load the solution from the jump list (which is about 95% of the time) Browser Link is disabled.
However, if I open Visual Studio and then open the solution from within Visual Studio Browser Link is enabled.

This could still be an add-on issue so to help identify the real problem I would be interested to know if anyone else has experienced a similar problem.

Thanks

Comment: I submitted a bug on Microsoft Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814830/browser-link-is-disabled-when-the-solution-is-not-opened-from-within-visual-studio-2013